# Is it guaranteed that two update requests return distinct results?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've been looking for an answer for days without any luck.
I need to know what's the expected behavior when two machines update a remote database simultaneously.

**Update method**

```
async function update () {
  const filters = { orderNumber: 1, paid: false }
  const updates = { paid: true }
  const { modifiedCount } = await OrderModel.updateOne(filters, updates)
}
```

Is it guaranteed that `modifiedCount` will always be 0 for one machine and 1 for another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/):

> MongoDB uses locking and concurrency control to prevent clients from modifying the same data simultaneously.

And:

> In addition to a shared (S) locking mode for reads and an exclusive (X) locking mode for write operations, intent shared (IS) and intent exclusive (IX) modes indicate an intent to read or write a resource using a finer granularity lock.

So exists a lock exclusive (X) for write operations.

So yes, only one updating will be doing at the same time.

Also checks [What locks are taken by some common client operations?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-locks-are-taken-by-some-common-client-operations-)

| Operation | Database | Collection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Update data | Exclusive | Exclusive |

Comment: I can't thank you enough, good sir! I wish you the best! You're the best!